# How to make Integration Tests against Google Drive with Service Account without an Enterprise Google account

Tags: google-drive-api, sandbox

We need a "google drive enterprise sandbox" or some sort of way to Mock a realistic *Enterprise* Google Drive account. This would make it so that we can simulate service accounts with access to multiple users files over a google enterprise account.

We can test a single GoogleDrive user no problem. But the enterprise service accounts with access to multiple users' files is not possible without an enterprise google account which is expensive.

Our app has access to google enterprise users files and using the service account can do operations on them.

This means in order to write integration tests we need an Enterprise google account to connect to. But that's pretty expensive and not possible from a budget standpoint.

How can we get something to run integration tests against that doesn't cost us a fortune?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accounts are USD5 per month (as at January 2017) but you can create a [full Google Enterprise (GSuite) account](https://www.google.com/a/signup/) at no cost as a trial. It is valid for 14 days.

You should be able to create a few users and some drive files for each of them. There are some limitations but mostly they're around how much email you can send programmatically.

You can keep the domain live for longer than 14 days with just 1 paid user and pay by the month for any more users by adding and removing them as and when required.

Comment: I used up my trial long time ago. I had mentioned that in the question. But thanks for the answer anyways.

Comment: ignore my earlier comment. the 14 days trial is all fine and well but i need integration tests to persist. tried to use wiremock recording and it didn't end up working when playing it back. any other ideas?

Comment: so if i had 5 accounts an enterprise account would only be 25$ a month?

Comment: Yes @NicholasDiPiazza. Updated my answer with info.

Comment: Hey thanks! that does help a lot. i'll see if this works out sounds like it should.

Comment: Just an update i have an enterprise account with 2 users and i pay 20$ a month.

Comment: OK after we are in production now ouch - we are getting hurt by the lack of our multiple users and multiple groups testing. we need a sandbox-able platform to test with.