# test google drive account - can I get one for free for dev / test?

Tags: testing, google-drive-api, integration-testing, google-apps

We need a test "google drive business sandbox" or some way to mock a realistic Google Drive Business account. As a security SaaS startup, our goal is to call the Google Drive (Business) APIs and retrieve information about access and permissions. We want to test 15-20 users for scale testing

However, there seems to be no way to set up a sandbox test account without setting up a full enterprise account - which is expensive at $10/user/month for a startup to afford.

This means in order to write tests we need an Business google account to connect to. But that's pretty expensive and not possible from a budget standpoint.

How can we get something to run tests against that doesn't cost us a fortune?

Comment: If you only want to use the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/), then you don't need to pay in order to use it. According to this [page](https://support.google.com/payments/answer/6224192?hl=en), there are no fees for making purchases on Google services like Google Play or Google Drive. You only pay for your purchases, applicable taxes, and delivery fees.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Integration Tests against Google Drive with Service Account without an Enterprise Google account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41490785/how-to-make-integration-tests-against-google-drive-with-service-account-without)